# How to partially reload a ui:repeat?

Tags: java, jquery, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

We've got a web application built on JBoss 7.1 with **JSF2** and Primefaces 3.3.

On one of our page, there is a `ui:repeat` displaying 10 items; then the user can click on some kind of "show more" button and 10 more items are displayed through ajax. The user can click the "show more" button until there is no more items to show. Note: This is not pagination, the displayed list gets longer with each click on "show more".

In fact, when the user clicks on the button, the server returns the old items and the new ones, and the client side of JSF must rebuild the whole repeater through jQuery each time.

We would like to find a better and more performant solution. The old items don't change between the *n-1* and the *n* call, so it would be more efficient if the server could only return through ajax the 10 new items.

Is it possible in JSF2 ? JSF seems not really compliant with this kind of recursive rendering. The only component that maybe could help us would be a TreeNode component, but it seems a bit of a hack :-/

Comment: If I got you right, you have an initial list with n items and at first you show 10, then you want to show the next 10, and on, like a pagination. I guess you have 2 lists in your backing bean: 1 with the whole list item and the second with 10 length that is filled on every ajax request, right?

Comment: It's quite that, but it's not a pagination: we want to display the 10 first items, then the 20 first items (10 old, 10 new), something like a kind of facebook wall

Comment: @XavierPortebois: I also wondered whether you use pagination or just add to the list. I edited your question to clarify (feel free to correct it).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's nothing like that in the standard JSF API. <del>Also nothing comes to mind in PrimeFaces.</del> For PrimeFaces see the update at the end

The [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) [`<o:componentIdParam>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/componentIdParam) may however be exactly what you're looking for. It allows you to let JSF render only a subset of the component tree based on a specific request parameter, which can be a component ID or a client ID. You could basically just use jQuery's [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) to reload the `<ui:repeat>` along with the start index as a request parameter and use jQuery's [`$.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to append it to the HTML DOM.

Here's a complete kickoff example. The view:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui"
>
    <f:metadata>
        <o:componentIdParam componentIdName="componentId" />
    </f:metadata>
    <h:head>
        <title>Stack Overflow Question 11364006</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script> <!-- Substitute with PrimeFaces' one, if necessary. -->
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <ul id="items">
            <ui:repeat id="itemsRepeater" value="#{bean.items}" var="item">
                <li>#{item}</li>
            </ui:repeat>
        </ul>
        <input type="button" id="showMore" value="Show more"/>
        <h:outputScript>
            $("#showMore").click(function() {
                $items = $("#items");
                var params = { start: $items.find("li").length, componentId: "itemsRepeater" };
                $.get(location, params, function(html) {
                    $items.append(html);
                });
            });
        </h:outputScript>   
    </h:body>
</html>
```

The backing bean:

```java
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Bean {

    private List<String> items;

    @ManagedProperty("#{param.start}")
    private int start;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // Just a stub. Do your thing to fill the items.
        items = new ArrayList<String>();
        int size = start + 10;

        for (int i = start; i < size; i++) {
            items.add("item " + (i + 1));
        }
    }

    public void setStart(int start) {
        this.start = start;
    }

    public List<String> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

}
```

---

**Update**: a live demo can be found in the "Expandable list" example of [the `<o:componentIdParam>` page of current showcase application](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/componentIdParam).

**Update 2)**: PrimeFaces `p:datascroller` has [lazyloading with 'on demand scrolling'](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datascroller/basic.xhtml)

Comment: I'm on vacation from tonight, so I cannot try this, but sounds promising. If Omnifaces easily compliant with Primefaces?

Comment: Yes. Even more, the OmniFaces showcase webapp uses PrimeFaces for UI. As to the kickoff example, it's copy'n'paste'n'runnable (after auto-organizing the imports, of course) and works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

For situations like this, I completely bypass JSF and use JAX-RS service with jQuery AJAX. That approach will help you build much better applications than just the AJAX support from JSF. Here is the basic technique.

In the XHTML page, simply have a placeholder for the list:

```
<div id="item_list"></div>

<a href="#" onclick="loadNext();">Load more...</a>
```

When the page loads, make an AJAX request to populate the initial list. Here is sample code. There may be typos, but you get the idea.

```
var nextStart = 0;

$(function() {
    loadNext();
});

function loadNext() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "api/items?start=" + nextStart,
        success: function(data) {
            appendToList(data);
            nextStart += data.length;
        }
    });
}

function appendToList(data) {
    //Iterate through data and add to DOM
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        $("#item_list").append($("<p>", {text: data.productName}));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this works well in many cases. However, you cannot use JSF components inside the table (e.g. buttons).