# Scroll down and load more data to ui:repeat

Tags: jsf, primefaces, omnifaces

Am building an application using jsf 2.3 and primefaces 6.2 when scroll down i want to load more data and append it to the old one. bellow are my code.

My JSF code

```
<h:commandScript name="loadMoreTimeline" execute="@this" render=":postForm:panelBlock" action="#{timelineBean.loadMoreTimeline()}" />     

<h:panelGroup id="panelBlock" styleClass="panelBlock" layout="block">
   <ui:repeat id="timelineRepeater" value="#{timelineBean.timelineList}" var="timeline">
     <div data-id="#{timeline.postId}">
       <h:outputText escape="false" value="#{timeline.content}" />
     </div>
   </ui:repeat>
</h:panelGroup>
```

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class TimelineBean implements Serializable {
  private List<Timeline> timelineList;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
     //loaded initially and contains the first N records.
     timelineList = feedService.getTimelines();

  }

  // SQL - SELECT * FROM timeline WHERE post_id < 'post_id' ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT 10
  public void loadMoreTimeline() {
    String lastId = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("lastId");
    long postId = Long.valueOf(lastId);
    timelineList.addAll(feedService.getTimelines(postId));
  }

  public List<Timeline> getTimelineList() {
    return timelineList;
  }


}
```

Jquery code

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() === $(document).height() - $(window).height()) { 
    //get the last div postid
    var lastId = $('.post-item:last').attr('data-id');
    // calling my commandScript
    loadMoreTimeline({lastId: lastId"});
  }
});
```

The above code works very well but it renders all the component tree inside the panelBlock div. I want a situation where it will render only a subset of the component tree based on a specific request parameter.

So i came across Omnifaces  component that render just one or more components on a view via a GET parameter. [How to partially reload a ui:repeat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364006/how-to-partially-reload-a-uirepeat) My problem is how will it work with my code. Because postConstruct will initially load the first N records, how will i call the loadMoreTimeline() method.

```
<h:outputScript>
        $("#showMore").click(function() {
            $items = $("#items");
            var params = { start: $items.find("li").length, componentId: "itemsRepeater" };
            //jQuery's $.get() reload the <ui:repeat>
            $.get(location, params, function(html) {
                $items.append(html);
            });
        });
</h:outputScript>
```

Comment: Check my edit to the answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364006/how-to-partially-reload-a-uirepeat. Does it help?

Comment: I have checked it out. The <p:dataScroller /> has a border which can be edited, if i have millions recorrds it will initially load all of it in the list then release it bit by bit using chunkSize. In production is this really good? How can i change the loading indicator and i would love to append a message below if there is no more record?

Comment: It has lazyloading too. The showcase java part is just a 'minimal' example and assumes you know the basics to make it lazyloading. Stackoverflow helps too btw for that

Comment: I think i can make it to be lazy loading, even Primefaces has LazyDataModel. I want to have full control when i scroll down. How can i replace the loading indicator that shows up when the scroll is down and i want to append a message if there is no more record. Or apart from Primefaces DataScroller is there no other solution to solve this issue with JSF.

Comment: New questions in new questions please (client-side it is all css (and html and javascript). Doing  it wih plain jsf jquery etc  gives you a little more conrtol but make it more complex amd you'd effectively be developing a datascroller

Comment: Has powerful as JSF this shouldn't be a difficult thing. This can be done easily with other programming languages. I expected JSF programmers to flood here with different solutions because every modern applications has infinite data loading while scrolling. A lot of young JSF programmers like me out there needs this solution. Please i would love it for you to show us if you have an idea doing it with plain JSF, Jquery and Ajax where it gives you full control, or if you can enhance @BalusC solution using Omnifaces componentIdParam.

Comment: No with jquery you need something like 'datatables' or whatever as well or tree components etc in **addition** to plain jquery if you want advanced components. Basic jsf is like using basic jquery **without** jquery-ui and additional components. And don't forget that if you have plain jquery you need lots of things like owasp security etc that JSF provides out of the box. (Not to forget making all responsivness that PF components have etc) All reasons I did not switch to all these  hyped javascript  frameworks (jquery ui basics is fine though) and can 'out-develop' others with advanced ui's.

Comment: So please compare apples with apples and not with oranges or grapes or ...

Comment: But let me try to get the real technical question behind this functional/business problem clear (get all the noise out of it). You need to call a server side method in a bean from a javascript function? (assuming the detection of 'last-visible-row-is-reached' works). Is that correct?

Comment: From my code, when scrolled down i called a method in a bean using the commandScript component with the last visible row ID to query the database to load more which works well but but it renders all the component tree inside the panelBlock div. I want a situation where it will render only a subset of the component tree based on a specific request parameter.

Comment: From Omnifaces showcase the componentidparam can render just one or more components on a view, is it possible to combine the componentidparam and commandScript, while the commandScript calls a method in a bean.